# Using Excel Dynamic Array Filter function on multiple criteria in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, function, filter, dynamic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9iVc.jpg)Earlier, I have received helped here while trying to use the Excel "Filter" dynamic array function to filter a table directly into an array in VBA (not directly in Excel).

[Has any one used Excel's Dynamic Array function "Filter" in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76675149/has-any-one-used-excels-dynamic-array-function-filter-in-vba)

This was done on a single criteria field. I have been tried to use it on multiple fields/criteria but could not convert the formula in VBA for it although it can be done directly into Excel as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h3LO.png)